# How to sign transaction with a generated keypair instead of provider in anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, transactions, rust, signature

I am currently working on "CreateAccount" test on solana, i am using provider and it automatically signs transactions so it is working but i want to test a new user so i want to create account by passing keypair to signers instead of provider.

My Anchor Version: 0.25.0

**Rust Code:**

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUserAccount<'info> {
    // User's account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    // Creating a new account for every user with seed of their wallet address.
    // This constraint one-account per wallet address
    #[account(
        init, 
        payer = signer, 
        space = UserAccount::LEN, 
        seeds = ["user-account".as_bytes(), signer.key().as_ref()], 
        bump,
    )] 
    pub user_account: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

**Working frontend test:**

```
describe('teamdao-tournament', () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env()
  anchor.setProvider(provider)

  const program = anchor.workspace.TeamdaoTournament as Program<TeamdaoTournament>

  it('Creating a new account for user', async () => {
    const ix = await program.methods.createUserAccount().accounts().signers();
    const userAccountAddress = (await ix.pubkeys()).userAccount;
    console.log('User account address :: ', userAccountAddress.toString())

    const tx = await ix.rpc()
    console.log('Your transaction signature', tx)
  }
}
```

**What i want to do (not working):**

```
describe('teamdao-tournament', () => {

  const program = anchor.workspace.TeamdaoTournament as Program<TeamdaoTournament>

  const newUser = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
  it('Creating a new account for user', async () => {
    const ix = await program.methods.createUserAccount().accounts({
      signer: newUser.publicKey
    }).signers([newUser]);
    const userAccountAddress = (await ix.pubkeys()).userAccount;
    console.log('User account address :: ', userAccountAddress.toString())

    // Create user's facebook address
    const tx = await ix.rpc()
    console.log('Your transaction signature', tx)
 }
}
```

second one getting error: "Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1"

How to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to airdrop SOL to the `newUser` keypair before using it to pay for transactions

Comment: I was requesting airdrop but not confirming transaction after adding that it worked:



`await program.provider.connection.confirmTransaction`

Answer (score 2):

You might find it useful to create a program for your mock user so you can send a tx from their "provider":

```
export const createTestUserProgram = (program: Program, wallet: KeyPair) => {
  const userProgram = new Program(
    program.idl,
    program.programId,
    new AnchorProvider(program.provider.connection, new Wallet(wallet), {})
  );
  return userProgram;
};
```

You may also need to transfer some SOL to this fake wallet to pay for tx fees, you can send it from the provider wallet:

```
  const fundTx = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
      toPubkey: userWallet.publicKey,
      lamports: 1000 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    })
  );
  await provider.sendAndConfirm(fundTx, [wallet.payer]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import {  LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from '@solana/web3.js';
    const user1KP = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    let token_airdrop = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(user1KP.publicKey, 
       10 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(token_airdrop);
```